# how to number sequences with the same name in bed file

Tags: shell, awk, paste

I have a file bed like this.

```
    KQ4156  0       34      Simple_repeat   .   +
    KQ4156  35      64      Simple_repeat   .   +
    KQ4156  1759    1822    Simple_repeat   .   +
    KQ4156  1901    2059    Simple_repeat   .   -
    KQ4156  2112    2258    DNA/hAT-Charlie .   +
    KQ4156  2890    2964    Simple_repeat   .   +
    KQ4156  4085    4130    DNA/hAT-Charlie .   +
    KQ4156  5587    5619    Simple_repeat   .   +
    KQ4156  5931    5995    SINE/tRNA-Deu   .   -
```

for subsequent analysis I need to distinguish the same elements. es. `simple_repeats_1, simple_repeats_2,` etc. and `DNA/hAT-Charlie_1, DNA/hAT-Charlie_2,` etc.... for all of the elements. 
the script used is this:

`awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{if(NR>3) {if($9=="C"){strand="-"}else{strand="+"};print $5,$6-1,$7,$11,".",strand}}' file.fa.out > file.bed`

how can I modify it in order to get what I'm looking for? I thought about applying `paste` but I don't know how to apply it for all the sequences

Comment: Why not just number the whole file? `nl file`?

Comment: Because I need to distinguish the elements with identical names in genes

Comment: Aaaand when you number the whole file you can distinguish any line, so you can distinguish any genes, so?

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awk solution using a table is the simplest:

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{ seen[$4]++; $4=$4"_"seen[$4]; print; }' file
```

will output:

```
KQ4156  0   34  Simple_repeat_1 .   +
KQ4156  35  64  Simple_repeat_2 .   +
KQ4156  1759    1822    Simple_repeat_3 .   +
KQ4156  1901    2059    Simple_repeat_4 .   -
KQ4156  2112    2258    DNA/hAT-Charlie_1   .   +
KQ4156  2890    2964    Simple_repeat_5 .   +
KQ4156  4085    4130    DNA/hAT-Charlie_2   .   +
KQ4156  5587    5619    Simple_repeat_6 .   +
KQ4156  5931    5995    SINE/tRNA-Deu_1 .   -
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {$4=$4"_"++count[$4]} 1'  Input_file
```